# Remove NaN rows from numpy array that also contain objects

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array, I want to identify which rows contain NaN values and objects.
For example, a row would contain both a float value and a list.

For the input array `arr`, I tried doing `arr[~np.isnan(arr).any(axis=1)]` but then I get the error message

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could 
not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: You can try doing `arr[~np.isnan(arr, casting = 'no').any(axis=1)]` or `arr[~np.isnan(arr, casting = 'unsafe').any(axis=1)]`

Comment: seems like you have different dtypes in your array. `np.isnan` is intended for nummeric, floating point type arrays - so maybe you can pre-select that part of your array which can be converted to float bevor applying `np.isnan`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta, I tried your suggestions on `np.array([5., np.nan, 'asdf'])` - gives me a similar / the same `TypeError` as @Anonymous experiences.

Comment: Given an example array.  I assume the dtype is `object`.

Comment: For example, if the array is `np.array([[1, [2,3], np.nan], [3, [5,6,7], 8]])`, I would want to get rid of the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [314]: x = np.array([[1, [2,3], np.nan], [3, [5,6,7], 8]])                                                
In [315]: x                                                                                                  
Out[315]: 
array([[1, list([2, 3]), nan],
       [3, list([5, 6, 7]), 8]], dtype=object)
In [316]: x.shape                                                                                            
Out[316]: (2, 3)
In [317]: x[0]                                                                                               
Out[317]: array([1, list([2, 3]), nan], dtype=object)
In [318]: x[1]                                                                                               
Out[318]: array([3, list([5, 6, 7]), 8], dtype=object)
```

`isnan` works on a float dtype array; object dtype can't be converted to that:

```
In [320]: np.isnan(x)                                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-320-3b2be83a8ed7> in <module>
----> 1 np.isnan(x)

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

We can, though, test the elements one by one with a `is np.nan` test:

```
In [325]: np.frompyfunc(lambda i: i is np.nan,1,1)(x)                                                        
Out[325]: 
array([[False, False, True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=object)
```

`frompyfunc` returns an object dtype; let's convert that to bool:

```
In [328]: np.frompyfunc(lambda i: i is np.nan,1,1)(x).astype(bool)                                           
Out[328]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
In [329]: np.any(_, axis=1)           # test whole rows                                                                       
Out[329]: array([ True, False])
In [330]: x[~_, :]                    # use that as mask to keep other rows                                                      
Out[330]: array([[3, list([5, 6, 7]), 8]], dtype=object)
```

The pandas `isnull` suggested in the other answer, can do a similar element by element test:

```
In [335]: pd.isnull(x)                                                                                       
Out[335]: 
array([[False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]])
```